# Pi up and running. SSHD and ping work. Then they stop working

Tags: networking, ssh, ping

I have a raspberry pi 3 running out at my gate 'handling things'. It has a dedicated static IP on my local lan connected via ethernet. After one of the raspbian updates recently, at some point, maybe 5 days later, maybe 4 hours later, I am no longer able to ping or ssh into the pi. When I walk out to it, it is running (red status light on it) and ethernet is alive (small switch at the gate shows activity), however as I said I can't ping or do anything to it. I haven't yet dragged a display/keyboard out there but I fear that is my next step. I don't know how to get it to stop doing this or what log file to look at for why networking just fails at some point. It ran for years with a prior raspbian. Any suggestions on where to look? thanks
Joe

Comment: Welcome! Without being there I will take a SWAG and say it is a power problem. Can you post an annotated schematic, not a frizzy picture. Be sure to show all connections and links to each of the hardware devices giving technical details.

Comment: `journalctl --full` will open the journal in a pager and let you look though the log. As to the cause, make sure you are using the RaspberryPi power-supply or USB connector. Generic aftermarket supplies have always caused issues if they deliver less current than needed. Many forum posts discuss the issue.

Comment: Good suggestion on the journalctl. Looking back to  when it went offline I found this:
Apr 07 08:57:14 gate dhcpcd[479]: eth0: hardware address ce:20:d7:d4:4a:eb claims 10.0.1.65
Apr 07 08:57:15 gate dhcpcd[479]: eth0: 10 second defence failed for 10.0.1.65
Apr 07 08:57:16 gate dhcpcd[479]: eth0: hardware address ce:20:d7:d4:4a:eb claims 10.0.1.65
Apr 07 08:57:16 gate dhcpcd[479]: eth0: DAD detected 10.0.1.65
I'm searching for a device with that MAC address on my network - haven't found it yet-but whatever it is doesn't ping after it takes over that reservation which is interesting.
Joe

Comment: I ran out of chars - would have added this to the bottom of my comment above - Regardless I think I'm on track to finding it. Worst case I can give this pi a new reserved IP and just avoid .65.

Thanks for the suggestions!